# How to printf Json Array Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

After `Json_decode` I have this `array Json` from database like this

`$infor = [ "name", "Mit", "age", "23" ]`

How can I print it in blade like this:

```
name: Mit

age: 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Array usage is wrong but you can do it with a technique.

```
{{ $infor[0] }} : {{ $infor[1] }}
{{ $infor[2] }} : {{ $infor[3] }}
```